# where does FocusScope widget exist in the widget tree?

Tags: flutter, dart

Where does the FocusScope widget create in the tree and we pass every context in it and it can request to any focus nodes. When we pass context to FocusScope it will start looking above the context and we never used the FocusScope widget in the code in the hierarchy where does it create and how does it resolves in the case of scaffold if we pass context that is above in the tree then it throws an exception then we use builder type of thing but in FocusScope why it doesn't throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example for the FocusScope

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

 
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// A demonstration pane.
///
/// This is just a separate widget to simplify the example.
class Pane extends StatelessWidget {
  const Pane({
    Key? key,
    required this.focusNode,
    this.onPressed,
    required this.backgroundColor,
    required this.icon,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final FocusNode focusNode;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Widget icon;
  final Widget? child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: child,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: IconButton(
              autofocus: true,
              focusNode: focusNode,
              onPressed: onPressed,
              icon: icon,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool backdropIsVisible = false;
  FocusNode backdropNode = FocusNode(debugLabel: 'Close Backdrop Button');
  FocusNode foregroundNode = FocusNode(debugLabel: 'Option Button');

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    backdropNode.dispose();
    foregroundNode.dispose();
  }

  Widget _buildStack(BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    final Size stackSize = constraints.biggest;
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      // The backdrop is behind the front widget in the Stack, but the widgets
      // would still be active and traversable without the FocusScope.
      children: <Widget>[
        // TRY THIS: Try removing this FocusScope entirely to see how it affects
        // the behavior. Without this FocusScope, the "ANOTHER BUTTON TO FOCUS"
        // button, and the IconButton in the backdrop Pane would be focusable
        // even when the backdrop wasn't visible.
        FocusScope(
          // TRY THIS: Try commenting out this line. Notice that the focus
          // starts on the backdrop and is stuck there? It seems like the app is
          // non-responsive, but it actually isn't. This line makes sure that
          // this focus scope and its children can't be focused when they're not
          // visible. It might help to make the background color of the
          // foreground pane semi-transparent to see it clearly.
          canRequestFocus: backdropIsVisible,
          child: Pane(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
            focusNode: backdropNode,
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
            onPressed: () => setState(() => backdropIsVisible = false),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                // This button would be not visible, but still focusable from
                // the foreground pane without the FocusScope.
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => debugPrint('You pressed the other button!'),
                  child: const Text('ANOTHER BUTTON TO FOCUS'),
                ),
                DefaultTextStyle(
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!,
                    child: const Text('BACKDROP')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        AnimatedPositioned(
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          top: backdropIsVisible ? stackSize.height * 0.9 : 0.0,
          width: stackSize.width,
          height: stackSize.height,
          onEnd: () {
            if (backdropIsVisible) {
              backdropNode.requestFocus();
            } else {
              foregroundNode.requestFocus();
            }
          },
          child: Pane(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            focusNode: foregroundNode,
            // TRY THIS: Try changing this to Colors.green.withOpacity(0.8) to see for
            // yourself that the hidden components do/don't get focus.
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            onPressed: backdropIsVisible
                ? null
                : () => setState(() => backdropIsVisible = true),
            child: DefaultTextStyle(
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!,
                child: const Text('FOREGROUND')),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use a LayoutBuilder so that we can base the size of the stack on the size
    // of its parent.
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: _buildStack);
  }
}
```